# How can I get a program to return True for an integer with all odd digits?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

The question asks to make a program that would return true if a given integer has digits that are all odd within it and false otherwise.

I got something simple working but it only works when the numbers are in a list and not just when they are given as integers.

input:

```
def test3(n):

  for x in n:
    print (x%2 != 0)

test3([13579])
```

Output:

```
True
```

input:

```
def test3(n):

  for x in n:
    print (x%2 != 0)

test3(13579)
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 86, in <module>
    test3(13579)
  File "main.py", line 83, in test3
    for x in n:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Expected Output:

```
True
```

There was a hint that was given for the question as well which is:
Hint:

````
To extract the lowest digit of a positive integer n, use the expression n % 10. To extract all other digits except the lowest one, use the expression n // 10. Or, if you don't want to be this fancy, first convert the number into a string and work there. (There is a more general and fundamental idea hidden in plain sight in this technique.)```
````

Comment: Your first version is wrong anyway. You test the whole number, not the digits - check `test3([21])`.

Answer (score 2):

You are messing with integer and string types. For iterating over the digits, we have to turn the integer into a string first, and then reconvert each digit into an integer to check whether it is odd or even. This is kindly ignoring the hint given, but I think it is even more elegant than the way the hint suggests :) (But this is debatable.)

```
def odd_digits_only(number: int) -> bool:  # this is equal to
# def odd_digits_only(number):
   for digit in str(number):
       if int(digit) % 2 == 0:
           return False
   return True
```

This could be shortened using list comprehension and `all`:

```
def odd_digits_only(number: int) -> bool:
    return all([int(digit) % 2 != 0 for digit in str(number)])
```

Comment: digit is a char (string) here, you can't do `%2`

Comment: @h4z3 You are totally right. This was a slip of the pen and I edited the post and added correct type conversion just when you wrote your comment.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Thanks for the reply!  What does "(number: int) -> bool" do? Is there simpler way that I can convert the integer to a string. I'm fairly new to programming and I think that the way you converted the integer to a string is a little too advanced for me.

Comment: @FarhanIqbal This actually "does" nothing, it is just a type hint, which says that the function `odd_digits_only()` takes one parameter (named `number`) which must be an Integer and returns a Boolean. Sorry, I am used to using this, and hence I also incorporate it into my answers here at SO, even if this is a bit off-topic in your question and not mandatory at all - but I consider it good practice. For more information have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html